# GM_xmlhttpRequest in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, greasemonkey, google-chrome-extension

When I try to use this in chrome to access a simple API I wrote, it throws this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://67.19.91.186/~needsed/api/get/ZEZrBZYIynQ. Origin http://bestofyoutube.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

From the reading I've been doing, it looks like it's an issue with XSS. Is it really impossible to access APIs in chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct.  According to the [issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=18857#c111), they're planning to do it, though.

In the mean time, you can instead use an [extension](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html).

Comment: Ugh. I was hoping this wasn't the case.

Answer (score 2):

The TamperMonkey extension provides a fully functioning Greasemonkey API, including cross-domain GM_xmlhttpRequest.

https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo

The Black Canvas Script Handler extension does the same, with an improved GUI:

https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/pipnnjjknlabchljabhmnpdfpdobpnkk

A solution of my own was to simulate GM XHR requests via a JSONP proxy:

http://hwi.ath.cx/javascript/xhr_via_json/

As well as requiring the proxy, it also opens a security hole, because the callback function must be embedded in unsafeWindow.  But at least it doesn't require the user to install any extra extensions!

Let's hope they get around to supporting it for 2011.  :)